# How to append items in dictionary nested list?

Tags: python

I have a file with two columns of data, for example:

```
1  5
1  6
2  3
3  4
3  5
...
```

I want to obtain a dictionary with first column as the key and the second column as values, something like the following:

```
B = {1 : [5,6], 2: [3], 3: [4,5]}
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: which part of the code can't you figure out exactly? I can point you to [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: Loop through each line of the file, `split()` the line to a list. Test if the first item in the list is already a key in the dictionary, if so append the second item in the list to it; if not, then create a new list for that key. Please share where in this you are stuck and we can help guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified full details of the content of your file. I am assuming you don't have any column names. With that if you use pandas, the solution will look like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('example.txt', header=None)
out = df.groupby(0).agg(list).to_dict()[1]
```

[`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) is used to read fixed width format files. the option `header=None` makes sure that the first row is not taken as column names.

Then you groupby the first column and aggregate the second column as list. Then use `to_dict()` to get a dictionary.

print(out):

```
{1: [5, 6], 2: [3], 3: [4, 5]}
```

Comment: Thanks, my file contains just two columns of integer values. Your solution works, but I cannot use non-default packages on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.groupby("column_name").apply(lambda x:x.values.flatten().tolist()).to_dict()
```